# Change background color of a specific a day in a jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery-ui-datepicker

I want to know how to set background color on the dates in a `datePicker`; I followed a lot of tutorials but I didn`t get any result.

I have this datePicker:

```html
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Comment: [Highlight Specific Dates in jQuery UI DatePicker](http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2012/05/highlight-specific-dates-in-jquery-ui.html)

Answer (score 9):

Just in case Mongoose's link goes bad someday it is best to post full answers here on StackOverflow:

Here is a working code snippet and screenshot of what the datepicker looks like using the [beforeShowDay](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay) function of the jQueryUI datepicker:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var SelectedDates = {};
    SelectedDates[new Date('04/05/2016')] = new Date('04/05/2016');
    SelectedDates[new Date('05/04/2017')] = new Date('05/04/2017');
    SelectedDates[new Date('06/06/2018')] = new Date('06/06/2018');

    $('#txtDate').datepicker({
        beforeShowDay: function(date) {
            var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
            if (Highlight) {
                return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
            }
            else {
                return [true, '', ''];
            }
        }
    });
});
```

```css
body
{
    font-family:Arial;
    font-size : 10pt;
    padding:5px;
}

.Highlighted a{
   background-color : Green !important;
   background-image :none !important;
   color: White !important;
   font-weight:bold !important;
   font-size: 12pt;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='txtDate' />
```

[image: What it looks like]

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/cqf9d/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=cqf9d

Documentation: [Jquery ui documentation on beforeShowDay](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Comment: It is working fine with the  jquery version in the example.